# Repeating block in Twig

Tags: twig

Is there anyway to repeat one block in twig like this:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | MyBusiness</title>

<meta name="title" content="{% block title %}{% endblock %} | MyBusiness"/>
```

In order to only declare the two blocks once? Like that:

```
{% block title %}   
The title I want to show in each title and metaTitle tags.{{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use an already defined block by writing `{{ block('blockName') }}`. So for your example you would do it like this:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | MyBusiness</title>

<meta name="title" content="{{ block('title') }} | MyBusiness"/>
```

See the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html) which points out nearly exact the same example